# Overloading binary operation symbols

Tags: notation

In computer science I'm used to using overloaded operators. Is this also valid in mathematical notation? Concretely, I have the following example:

Definition:

> Let $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and  $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ be two graphs.
> We define $\phi = \{(v,w) \in V_1 \times V_2 | v \text{ is mapped to } w \}$ be a mapping between vertices from these graphs, called an FU instance.
> We can say that a vertex $v_i$ is part of an FU instance $\phi$ iff: $\exists (v_i,x) \in \phi \lor \exists (x,v_i) \in \phi$; short-hand notation: $v \in \phi$.

Usage in question:

> Let $G=(V_G,E_G)$ be a graph, and $\Phi_G$ be a set of FU instances. We define:
> $V^*_G = \{ v \in V_G | n_v > 1\}$ where $ n_v = \#\{ \phi \in \Phi_G | v \in \phi \}$.

Is it appropriate to overload $\in$ in one statement, like that? In the case of $\phi \in \Phi_G$ it's the canonical set membership relation, while in $v \in \phi$ its my self-defined use.

If not, I can easily define my shorthand using a different symbol, but I feel this would make things harder to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's inappropriate, because $v\in \phi$ already has a meaning.  I would define a new object, say $$\phi^*=\{v\in V_1|\exists w\in V_2, (v,w)\in\phi\}\cup\{v\in V_2|\exists w\in V_1,(w,v)\in\phi\}$$ and then write $v\in \phi^*$.

Comment: You make a good point, about $ v \in \phi $ being already defined. I am unsure whether I like defining a new object like you propose, since $\phi$ is meaningful in my domain (its a mapping) while $\phi*$ is not really. It would be something like "the set of vertices that are part of a mapping". In this case I think I'd rather use a different operation symbol. Have you by any chance a suggestion what could be legible? I was thinking $\sqsubset$ because I don't use it anywhere else, but it kinda implies $v$ is a set, too. :/

Comment: Any symbol you like is okay, just so long as you define it.